# Failed to load resource - appendChild - for https

Tags: javascript, https

Please help me.
I have HTML code in SITE 1

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://site2.com/validator.php"></script>
<form action="/" method="post">
<input type="text" id="purse" name="purse" value="R" />
<input type="submit" value="Get" onclick="return get();" />
</form>
```

and file validator.php with function get() in SITE 2

```
<?
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
if(isset($_GET['purse'])){
?>
alert("GOOD!");
<?
}else{
?>
function get() {
    var js = document.createElement("script");
    var wmr_purse = document.getElementById("purse").value;
    js.type = "text/javascript";
    js.src = "/validator.php?purse=" + purse;
    document.body.appendChild(js);
    return false;
}
<?
}
?>
```

When there is a request from site 1 with http to the site 2 with https - everything works, but when there is a request from site 1 with https to site 2 with https - I see an error. How to fix it?

document.body.appendChild(js) - Failed to load resource

Comment: I guess that url is wrong

Comment: Address is correct. If I click the GET button on site 1 (http://www.site1.com) - everything works. If I click the button from a secure site (https://www.site1.com) - from https - an error.

Comment: Please open network tab and show the url that is loading and the one that is not loading